# How to reference data in array of hash in javascript: Windows 8 Metro

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I've got some data stored this way:

```
   var protossUnitsArray =
   [
      { name: "Zealot", health:"100", shield:"50", armor:"1", picture: "/images/protoss/zealotPortrait.png" },
      { name: "Stalker", health: "80", shield: "80", armor: "1", picture: "/images/protoss/stalkerPortrait.png" },
      { name: "Sentry", health: "40", shield: "40", armor: "1", picture: "/images/protoss/sentryPortrait.png" },
      { name: "High Templar", health: "40", shield: "40", armor: "0", picture: "/images/protoss/hightemplarPortrait.png" },
      { name: "Dark Templar", health: "40", shield: "80", armor: "1", picture: "/images/protoss/darktemplarPortrait.png" },
      { name: "Immortal", health: "200", shield: "100", armor: "1", picture: "/images/protoss/immortalPortrait.png" }
   ];

   var protossUnitsList = new WinJS.Binding.List(protossUnitsArray);

   var publicMembers =
   {
      itemList: protossUnitsList
   };

   WinJS.Namespace.define("ProtossUnitsData", publicMembers);
```

As you can see, the array has been made publicly available.

How do I actually reference data from this array from another javascript file?

Let's say I want to know what a Stalker's health is (which is 80). Let's assume I know Stalkers are always going to be the second item in the array, shouldn't it be something like

`ProtossUnitsData.itemList[1]['health']` ?

But that's not quite right..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Windows 8 and the UI formerly known as Metro, but in JavaScript shouldn't it just be:

```
ProtossUnitsData.itemList[1].health
```

### Edit

Looking at the documentation, it seems that `WinJS.Binding.List` exposes methods for working with the data in the List. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700774.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700753.aspx) for more info, but it looks like you want to use:

```
var item = ProtossUnitsData.getItem(1),
    data = item.health;
```

That might work...

Comment: hmm, Visual Studio autocomplete is saying ProtossUnitsData.itemList.getItem() is a thing. That gives me more things to play around with at least, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access 2nd item from the array `protossUnitsArray`, shouldn't it be:

```
protossUnitsArray[1].health
```

Comment: That array is not publicly accessible. The only thing publicly accessible is ProtossUnitsData. It should be possible to get to the array using that, I just can't work out the correct syntax

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! It's actually:

```
ProtossUnitsData.itemList.getAt(1).health;
```